# Synchronize multiple instances of Spring Cache with a Redis lock

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-cache, lettuce

I'm building a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Cache with a Redis backing store and needs to synchronize the updates made to the cache.

The caching is not made on the fly, but by an scheduled process that updates the cache periodically.

The algorithm I came up with is:

- periodically the instances will check if the Redis cache is older than some predetermined time
- if that's the case, the instance will try to acquire a lock on some Redis key
- if the instance successfully locks the key, it will then proceed with the update
- if some other instance already locked the key, move on
- all instances can still read the cache

Everything is more or less already built, all I need is to implement the locking/releasing mechanism.

Spring Cache is using Lettuce to interact with Redis, what is the best way to get an connection to Redis and manage the locking mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may already be aware, [Spring's Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache) provides simple coordination amongst multiple Threads in a single Spring [Boot] application process using the `sync` attribute on the `@Cacheable` annotation (see [ref doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-synchronized)).

> NOTE: Despite the comment ("*... use the `sync` attribute to instruct the underlying cache provider to lock the cache entry while the value is being computed. As a result, only one thread is busy computing the value, while the others are blocked until the entry is updated in the cache.*") in the documentation, the locking mechanics is handled by the core framework itself, and in most cases, not the provider.  Anyway...

However, this "coordination" is only per-process and will not work for multiple Spring [Boot] application instances, or (OS) JVM processes. In this case, you need some form of distributed locking across your multiple Spring [Boot] application instances to coordinates access to shared cache entries stored in the single Redis server (cluster) shared by your Spring [Boot] application instances.

I am no Redis expert (I am still learning), but I am familiar with similar NoSQL stores (Apache Geode/VMware GemFire, Hazelcast, etc) and distributed locking mechanisms. I see that distributed locking is possible to achieve with Redis as well. In a quick search, I found "[Distributed Locking](https://redis.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-6-application-components-in-redis/6-2-distributed-locking/)" in Redis, and specifically, "[Building a lock in Redis](https://redis.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-6-application-components-in-redis/6-2-distributed-locking/6-2-3-building-a-lock-in-redis/)". This is probably the best way to go.

In addition, if you want to make this distributed locking automatically/transparently available through Spring's Cache Abstraction, then you could possibly create a custom AOP Aspect and weave this Aspect together with the framework provided Caching Aspect (Interceptor), being conscious of ordering, as 1 idea.

Alternatively, you could implement wrapper implementations for the Spring `Cache` and `CacheManager` SPI interfaces that implement distributed locking on top of the core Redis `Cache` and `CacheManager` provider implementations provided by Spring Boot/Spring Data Redis.

Of course, there are multiple ways to go about this. Just tossing out more ideas, but have a look at the distributed locking information in the book.

Comment: I read the Distributed Locking page and I'm in the process of implementing it right now, but I was hoping that someone would offer some better idea than that

Comment: Understood; my apologies. Distributed locking is not a trivial task to implement if that is what you are truly after. Of course, it also all depends on your level of tolerance with respect to consistency/accuracy. I'll think on this more. However, Spring's Cache abstraction deliberately does not offer a simple solution here since no 2 caching providers are the same in this regard. Capabilities vary quite a bit between different caching providers I'm afraid, so it is difficult to generalize.

Comment: I am sure you have thought about this problem a lot and are quite familiar with the challenges by now, but I wanted to share this article on distributed locking by Hazelcast, as it is one of the better articles on the subject that I have read: https://hazelcast.com/blog/long-live-distributed-locks/. It nicely compares and contrasts distributed applications to multithreaded ones, which have many similarities but important differences, too.

Comment: No need to apologize, it was just a comment, thanks for the help